# Is it possible to mount Windows Azure VHD disk to my local machine

Tags: vhd, azure

I have a storage account on windows azure and I need to use one of my cloud VHD disk on my local machine. I know that it is possible to download whole image but I have no need of this. I am planing to copy some information from VHD.

Can azure VHD disk be mounted as local VHD without downloading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot mount a blob-backed vhd from Windows Azure to a local machine. You can only mount to Virtual Machines (whether Linux or Windows) and web/worker-role instances (as an Azure Drive).

One option, aside from downloading the vhd, is to build yourself a file server in a Virtual Machine (ftp, for example) that lets you browse/upload/download files from your vhd. This lets you keep your System of Record in one place (the blob-backed vhd).

Comment: How so? It's true that Azure Files is now available (SMB as a service), but it's in preview (and not directly related to this question). And it's true that there are 3rd-party tools that provide such an environment, but there's no Azure-supported method for mounting a vhd to an on-premises (non-Azure) machine.